# Azure DevOps: job fails with grey cross, without any error message

Tags: azure-pipelines

I have a pipeline in which I'm making some changes. Usually when there's an error in the syntax, definition, etc, there's a clear error message. However now I'm only getting a red or grey (depending on the view) x-mark/cross. There's no further information available it seems. Where can I find an actual actionable error message?

[image]

[image]

Note that there are no further logs. There's no 'view raw logs' option either.

[image]

Comment: You need to show the run log of the task for which the pipeline is failed.

Comment: @Jay that's the thing, there is no log. I had the same issue, and the accepted answer fixed it for me as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77071120/26226

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on empirical findings I've discovered the following. I was using a template to download from a specific pipeline resource. Then I started using this template in a pipeline that didn't define this pipeline resource. Fixing this reference solved the problem. I hope this helps someone as this is very hard to find out.

Template referencing the `build` pipeline resource:

```
steps:
- download: build
  artifact: Packages
```

Pipeline defining this pipeline resource:

```
# pipeline:
resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: build
```

My failing pipeline didn't define this pipeline resource. I wanted to reference the current pipeline in the template in this instance:

```
steps:
- download: current
  artifact: Packages
```

I solved this by introducing a parameter to the template:

```
parameters:
  - name: download

steps:
  - download: ${{ parameters.download }}
    artifact: Packages
```